# WCF Ajax service - How can I pass an Array or JSON to the service? What should the method parameter type be?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, wcf, serialization

I have a very simple WCF service I would like to pass it an array or json?

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string GetPreDisplay(string inputData)
    {
        //DoSomething with inputData
        return "Sweet!";
    }
```

My javascript...

```
 var data = [paymentControls['claimNum'], paymentControls['claimSeq']];
        $lps.GetPreDisplay(data, onComplete);
```

Obviously string is the wrong type. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
~ck

Answer (score 0):

With ASP.Net MVC you can return data as an ActionResult, there is a method "Json" which converts the data to the correct format. Have a look at this other question:

[wcf json web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824331/wcf-json-web-service)