# How to return JSON object to client without MVC references?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use JsonResult in MVC. Now I am working on a web form project without any references to MVC, and I cannot find a way to return a JSON object to the client. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) is a good start. And if you want more power you may checkout [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx). Both allow you to serialize CLR objects to JSON strings. If you are working with ASP.NET (not MVC) you could still use [PageMethods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) or [script enabled services](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx). Also worth mentioning that [WCF also supports JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/wcf-how-do-i-return-clean-json).

So, up to you to choose, play and ask if you encounter some problems implementing a specific solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.

Keep in mind that the version of .NET you are targeting will determine which assembly you need to reference:

- In 3.5, add reference to System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
- In 4, add reference to System.Runtime.Serialization