# How does one implement a .Net WebService that does not encapsulate response in XML?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I am writing an series of web interfaces to some data. I have WebMethods to return the data in DataSet and XmlDataDocument format (The XmlDataDocument removes all the schema overhead.)

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDataDocument Search_XML( string query ) {
  return new XmlDataDocument( Search_DataSet( query ) );
}
[WebMethod]
public DataSet Search_DataSet( string query ) {
  DataSet result = new DataSet( "SearchResults" );
  //... Populate DataSet here
  return result;
}
```

I have also created a function that accepts an XSL formatting string and returns the formated results, allowing the client to format an HTML response they can inject right into their webpage:

```
public string Search_XSL( string query, string xsl ) {
  string result = "";
  XmlDataDocument resultxml = Search_XML( query );
  XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
  using ( StringReader xslstringreader = new StringReader( xsl ) ) {
    using ( XmlReader xslxmlreader = XmlReader.Create( xslstringreader ) ) {
      using ( MemoryStream transformedmemorystream = new MemoryStream() ) {
        using ( StreamWriter transformedstreamwriter = new StreamWriter( transformedmemorystream ) ) {
          try {
            transform.Load( xslxmlreader );
            transform.Transform( resultxml, null, transformedstreamwriter );
            transformedstreamwriter.Flush();
            transformedmemorystream.Position = 0;
            using ( StreamReader transformedreader = new StreamReader( transformedmemorystream ) ) {
              result = transformedreader.ReadToEnd();
            }
          }
          catch ( Exception ex ) {
            result = ex.InnerException.ToString();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;

}
```

My question is, how do I implement a WebMethod-like interface for this Search_XSL() function so that I can return the resulting string exactly as the function does, without the XML encoding the WebMethod puts around it? Would that be a new Web Form? How do I implement a Web Form with no actual HTML, just accepting form parameters? Not sure where to start here.

Edit: It looks like a "Generic Handler" .ashx file is the way to go. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need an HTTP endpoint that processes an [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) and returns a custom response, then using [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) via a Generic Web handler (*.ashx) would be the correct approach to take.

You would read the values from the [request query string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) and then [process the request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx). Your generic handler would use the [HttpContext.Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.response.aspx) to set the [content type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype.aspx) of the output stream to *text/html* and would [write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw.aspx) the resulting HTML you wish to inject.

Answer (score 2):

WCF is the way to go in .net. You can configure your methods to return json or any number of of other type of serializations.  While a generic handler could work there is much better support for wcf.  Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/wcf-how-do-i-return-clean-json) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

WebMethods use SOAP, which means you can't remove the SOAP envelope at the service layer. Your original idea is right, here's what you need to finish:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        Response.Write("Hello world");
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
    }
```

It's a quick and dirty solution, but it works.