# Consuming .NET web service in iOS

Tags: ios, web-services

We have an existing .NET web service that we'd like to reuse when we port our .net project to iOS. I've seen wsdl2objc but I'm still having a hard time figuring out how to use the generated files.

could someone share some detailed step by step direction how to do this?

Comment: Did you try the [usage instructions](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions) on the wsdl2objc site?  If so, where did you have difficulties?

Comment: u can make your service restful, then you wont need the wsdl

Comment: on build, there were a few errors that came up. let me try redoing the whole steps again.

Comment: Please ignore everyone telling you to rewrite your whole stack to be buzzword compliant.  Wsdl isn't the nicest thing around, but it does work.

Comment: TokenMacGuy: "but it does work" in general (ofcoz) or "but it boes work WITH IOS"? if the second, would you please link some resources?

Comment: @boj: wsdl and ios does work according to the posts on wsdl2objc project in github. it's just that i'm new to iOS development, Xcode and Objective-C altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to switch to [JSON](http://www.json.org/):

JSON works well with .NET ([JSON service in 60 seconds](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec?display=Print), [How do I return clean JSON from a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/wcf-how-do-i-return-clean-json)) and iOS too ([JSON and iOS](http://petermcintyre.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/consume-json-rest-in-ios/)).

You'll find step-by-step tutorial in the second article.

Comment: the web service uses SOAP so how do I return JSON from that? we could probably convert it to a RESTful service but we'd like to reuse the current service as it is since existing modules are using it.

Comment: create new web service that call the WCF ?? I also face the same problem, my web developer build WCF but ios developer dislike to use it, he say, why we don't use simple HTTP Get/Post method to pass the input parameter .....