# Can't get JSON out of a WCF service

Tags: xml, wcf, json, web-services, soap

I can't seem to succeed with getting JSON out of a WCF service even if I tag the method with the attributes:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Product/{productIdString}",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

OR

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

I'm always getting XML, whether I return it as a `DataSet` or a `List<>`.

The only way that worked was to manually returning JSON as a string but it was also encapsulated in XML.

Any clue?

Comment: What **binding** are you using on your service?? The JSON stuff works pretty much only on the `webHttpBinding` (REST-Style WCF Services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "products")]
    public IList<JxProduct> GetProductList()
    {
        List<JxProduct> products = new List<JxProduct>();
        products.Add(new JxProduct { Description = "Tire", Id = 1, Price = 39.99});
        products.Add(new JxProduct { Description = "Tube", Id = 2, Price = 4.99 });
        products.Add(new JxProduct { Description = "Patch", Id = 3, Price = 3.99});

        return products;
    }
```

You can also review the following post which goes into more details about web.config settings.
[How do I return clean JSON from a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/wcf-how-do-i-return-clean-json)

Answer (score 0):

`[WebGet]` (and `[WebInvoke]`) attributes are only recognized by the `WebHttpBehavior` (`<webHttp/>` if you're using config). Make sure that the endpoint you're hitting has that behavior set.