# WCF service consumed by jQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf

I have been tasked with creating a service that will be consumed by jQuery on a public facing website. The site will not authenticate users so there is no need for security on the front end. 
How do I expose the WCF service so that it can't be browsed to and only consumed by the website? There's no sensitive data being returned but because of Auditing I cannot allow the service to be browsed to.

Ideas? Coded examples?

Comment: A couple places to start: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/wcf-how-do-i-return-clean-json/), [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) and [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/Nettuce/archive/2009/10/18/wcf-jquery-rest-json-service.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication not needed. The service was restricted using IIS binding so that it can only be accessed on the local machine which also hosts the site.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to implement authentication then.  As far as comsuming your WCF service, JSON is the best way to go.  Here is a good overview on what you need to do with your contract, etc to make it JSON compliant http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2010/02/01/Creating-a-WCF-Service-for-JSON.aspx