# Using json with WCF? Is it easy?

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I need to build a service layer. I needs to service an MVC UI layer. And it also needs to service native apps. I want to deliver everything in json because the packet size is small and I don't want multiple protocols to debug.

I like using SOAP however because it lets you easily build references using c#.

So im a bit stuck. Whats the best way to build a service layer to return json and automatically build from some contract? Is there a way?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/wcf-how-do-i-return-clean-json) might give you some hints. Or you could also consider building you service with [asp.net web api](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple json-serialization in your WCF operationContract method:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "myTpl")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable json by adding setting to your config under endpointBehaviors:

```
<webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
```