# How do I return Json serialized data from WCF?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

I have looked and around and seen that it is possible to return objects serialized into Json from a WCF web service. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your requesting client is sending the "Accept: application/json" header?

Comment: You can see bellow link :
[return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add attribute to the service like this

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ObjectName YourMethodName();
```

Comment: @Funky This will return Object serialized as JSON. Can you please elaborate a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you can set **automaticFormatSelectionEnabled** to true standardEndpoint of webHttpEndpoint in web.config like

```
<webHttpEndpoint>
  <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
</webHttpEndpoint>
```

And you need to add http header for json response to your client

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient("endpoint"))
{
     HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage("GET", "SomeMethod");                
     request.Headers.Accept.AddString("application/json");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a tutorial for this or link?