# AFNetworking can't get the responseObject

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I want to get the responseObject. I tried ASI but people offer me to try AFNetworking.But I keep getting error. Where am I doing wrong?With SOAPUI I can get the results. Thank you.

The method in wcf:

ListHastaAra(int kat,int oda,string hastaAdi,int protokolNo,int yatanAyaktan);

the url that I use "http://... /rest /HastaAra"
IOS part:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"kat": @"0",@"oda": @"0", @"hastaAdi":hastaAdi, @"protokolNo":@"0",@"yatanAyaktan":@"1"};

    [manager POST:HASTAARAIP parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

The error log is:

> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
>   UserInfo=0x8c47a30 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with
>   array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: The response you are getting back from your API is not the correct format or the JSON content-type is not being set in the header with the response, that is why you are getting an error and no responseObject.

Comment: I add 
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"]; but still same error.

Comment: Try the url in http requester and validate response json in http://jsonlint.com/. To set content type add "header('Content-Type: application/json');" to the first line of your php code at server which generate json

Comment: The server is wcf. What if I add endpoint informations again to the "manager"? <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" name="webEndPoint" contract="Name.MethodName"/> How can I do it?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service

Comment: Your server is not responding with valid JSON