# WCF service return JSON returned by yet another service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, httprequest

I am trying to write a WCF service (A) that is in turn calling another service (B). This is not a problem. The problem is that B returns json, and this I want to return from A. Here is the code I have:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("//url_to_B//");
        String username = "user";
        String password = "password";
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        wr.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        Stream resStream = wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader resReader = new StreamReader(resStream);
        String response = resReader.ReadToEnd();
        resReader.Close();
        resStream.Close();
        return response;
    }
}
```

and:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData(int value);
}
```

Outputs as found in Fiddler:
B:

```
[{"id":"10103","key":"CAMMOT"}]
```

A:

```
"[{\"id\":\"10103\",\"key\":\"CAMMOT\"}]"
```

The returned value from A if called is a string with data that can be parsed to json. How would I go about returning json instead? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the format of the string returned from `A`

Comment: added example return values I can see in Fiddler :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service maybe.

Comment: I was looking at that, but my problem is different. He has objects and can return a list of them. According to this I would have to parse the json to C# classes and then return these classes. Seems like too much work for a simple thing, provided the results I have shown you are like 1% of the returned object, they are huge, nested and complicated...

Comment: Wait, `A` returns a valid json. now, you want to return that same json from your call in `B`, but without the escaping inside the json?

Comment: A returns a string that contains data that can be parsed to json. I want to return from A data exactly as it is returned from B, no extra escapes, quotes around it etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning a `Stream`, you can return a raw string:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public System.IO.Stream GetData(int value)
    {
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("//url_to_B//");
        String username = "user";
        String password = "password";
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        wr.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        return wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WCF binding will use jsonSerializer as MessageEncoder if you specify

```
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
```

Then it will process string as part of Json object (a property) and encode the " as \" to avoid conflict with the json syntax.

Just remove the ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json and it should work as you want.