# How to convert datatable to json string output using json.net WCF Rest Service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

How to convert datatable to json string using json.net WCF Rest Service in c# WCF Application

Comment: Any effort so far? Please read [ask] and [help]

Comment: yes, i have done it, but when running it is showing the error "Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U should use JsonConvert.SerializeObject followed by the datatable in the first parameter, and then the way you want to format it in the 2nd parameter.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objAcctDTable, Formatting.None);
```

-edit-

if you are struggling with the escape quotes or slashes, you should put your string through this function before doing anything with it

```
public string EscapeQuotesMySql(string str)
        {

            string retVal = System.String.Empty;

            if (!System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {

                // replace special quotes

                retVal = str.Replace((char)8216, '\'');

                retVal = retVal.Replace((char)8217, '\'');

                // escapes for SQL

                retVal = retVal.Replace(@"\", @"\\");

                retVal = retVal.Replace(@"'", @"\'");

            }

            return retVal;

        }
```

Comment: I don't think you need to do that. WCF will handle the JSON conversion for you. Simply make the return type of the function DataTable. E.g. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service

Comment: How we can do the same for XML ?

Comment: Make the return type DataTable and configure the WCF to return XML. See my earlier comment - WCF does this all for you...