# Not getting proper JSON through c# web Service

Tags: c#, json, wcf

This is my web service IRestService.cs

```
 {

   [ServiceContract]
     public interface IRestServiceImpl
      {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
        string JSONData(string id);


        }
         }
```

This my JSON Helper Class

```
   public class JSONHelper
    {
      public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
      {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
       }

    public static string ToJSON(this object obj, int recursionDepth)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RecursionLimit = recursionDepth;
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
      }
```

My Service in which I am parsing a JSOn format type of string

```
    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
    #region IRestServiceImpl Members

    public string XMLData(string id)
    {
        return "You requested product " + id;
    }

    public string JSONData(string id)
    {
        id = @"{""contacts"":   [{""country"":""Pakistan"",""sunrise"":1381107633,""sunset"":1381149604}]}";
         return id;
    }

    #endregion

    }
  }
```

and this is the link i am using and getting Wrong JSON

http://116.58.61.180/Website/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/22

and JSON is

```
    {"JSONDataResult":"{\"contacts\":   [{\"country\":\"Pakistan\",\"sunrise\":1381107633,\"sunset\":1381149604}]}"}
```

What I am doing Wrong?
Why I am getting backslash in this JSON

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service)

Comment: Where did you see the backslashes? In the debugger? That's just the debugger adding backslashes just to confuse you.

Comment: This is format of JSON. Nothing wrong in this.

Comment: @Malaika If you must return JSON from your service as a string instead of object as suggested by Thangadurai linked, then after receiving the JSON string you replace "\ with ' using string replace and parse the JSON thereafter.

Comment: So, you didn't see those slashes in the debugger?

Comment: @MalaikaKhan Your return type is "string" and you are returning a JSON string which has double quotes in it. To escape it, WCF adds backslashes. To get rid of it you should implement a return type of System.IO.Stream in WCF.

Comment: @Siva can your write the exact line for Replacing the Slash

Comment: @MalaikaKhan Will you always return this string or this will be dynamic.

Comment: @Mairaj this will be dynamic but i am first trying this on static, first this static parse according to my need then i will work on dynamic

Comment: Ok than you need to return object of class of Contacts.

Comment: @Mairaj then please help me in this

Comment: Ok i ma posting sample service.

Comment: @Mairaj ok then please post that in list..

Comment: @Mairaj can you Email me this full fledged service\

Comment: Yes send me email to my email address given in my profile  i will send you complete code.

Comment: @Mairaj Mail Sent Please have a look

Comment: I will look at this when in home now in office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return `object or list of objects`.Have a look at below sample code. There is one GET method and one is POST. One method will return object of RequestData and one will return List of RequestData

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse)]
    List<RequestData> GetUser(Request data);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "UsersList/{id}",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    RequestData UsersList(string id);



}

public class DataService : IDataService
{

    public List<RequestData> GetUser(Request data)
    {
        List<RequestData> list = new List<RequestData>();
        if (data.Name.ToUpper() == "MAIRAJ")
        {
            list.Add(new RequestData
            {
                Name = "Mairaj",
                Age = 25,
                Address = "Test Address"
            });
            list.Add(new RequestData
            {
                Name = "Ahmad",
                Age = 25,
                Address = "Test Address"
            });
            list.Add(new RequestData
            {
                Name = "Minhas",
                Age = 25,
                Address = "Test Address"
            });
        }
        return list;
    }
    public RequestData UsersList(string userId)
    {
        if (userId == "1")
        {
            return new RequestData
            {
                Name = "Mairaj",
                Age = 25,
                Address = "Test Address"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new RequestData
            {
                Name = "Amir",
                Age = 25,
                Address = "Test Address"
            };
        }
    }

}
[DataContract]
public class RequestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Address { get; set; }

}
```

And here is web.config

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WCFWebApp.DataService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFWebApp.IDataService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What we have to include in Request Class ..public List<RequestData> GetUser(Request data).. Because i m getting error in this line . where the Request data is wrritten

Comment: GetUser(Request data) In this line

Comment: Its not Working when i am calling in URL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942042/not-getting-the-data-in-url-by-web-service?noredirect=1#comment44280084_27942042 please check this link .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942042/not-getting-the-data-in-url-by-web-service?noredirect=1#comment44280084_27942042  this is the web service I had made according to your post and now i m not getting the data in url

Comment: what are you typing in URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is "string" and you are returning a JSON string which has double quotes in it. To escape it, WCF adds backslashes.

To get rid of it you should implement a return type of System.IO.Stream in WCF. It is just a serialized form of the string.

Comment: {"JSONDataResult":"{\"contacts\":[{\"country\":\"Pakistan\",\"sunrise\":1381107633,\"sunset\":1381149604}]}"}               please help me in this correction

Comment: Add this at the end of your method before returning

byte[] x = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( << your JSON string goes here >>);

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";

    return new MemoryStream(x);

Also make sure your method return types are "System.IO.Stream"

Answer (score 0):

use some sort of json serializer that lets you serialize c# objects to json like t[his](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

Comment: even if you use a JSON Serializer to return a string, you would still have those backslashes.