# Not Getting the Data in URL by Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, url

I am making web service and not getting the parse data through URL
Code of WEB SERVICE is this. my IService class

```
  namespace DataService
 {

   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IService1
  {

     [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse)]
    List<RequestData> GetUser(RequestData data);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "UsersList/{id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    RequestData UsersList(string id);

     }


  [DataContract]
   public class RequestData 
   {
    [DataMember] 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    [DataMember] 
    public int Age { get; set; } 
    [DataMember] 
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

}

this is my service1 class inherited by Iservice1 Class

```
namespace DataService
{

    public class Service1 : IService1
   {

      public List<RequestData> GetUser(RequestData data)
      {
        List<RequestData> list = new List<RequestData>();
        if (data.Name.ToUpper() == "MAIRAJ")
        {
            list.Add(new RequestData
            {
                Name = "Mairaj",
                Age = 25,
                Address = "Test Address"
            });
            list.Add(new RequestData
            {
                Name = "Ahmad",
                Age = 25,
                Address = "Test Address"
            });
            list.Add(new RequestData
            {
                Name = "Minhas",
                Age = 25,
                Address = "Test Address"
            });
        }
        return list;
    }
    public RequestData UsersList(string userId)
    {
        if (userId == "1")
        {
            return new RequestData
            {
                Name = "Mairaj",
                Age = 25,
                Address = "Test Address"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new RequestData
            {
                Name = "Amir",
                Age = 25,
                Address = "Test Address"
            };
        }
        }
       }
    }
```

I am giving this URL after deploying web service http://116.58.61.180/ADG/Service1.svc
what Exact url should parse to get the data

this is my web.config

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>

   <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
   </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>
```

```
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your web.config?

Comment: @Pankaj yes i am posting this

Comment: Try this : http://116.58.61.180/ADG/Service1/UserList/1

Comment: @Pankaj still not getting anything

Comment: I have updated instructions in answer setion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot few things in your web.config :

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
        <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

And

```
<protocolMapping>
   <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>
```

If you don't put all this stuffs in your web.config you won't be able to get your services working.

The full Web.config would be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

For more details I had written few months ago a post on my blog about WCF and REST :

[Simple WCF and REST service](http://www.lechatcode.com/microsoft-net/simple-wcf-and-rest/)

[WCF and POST method](http://www.lechatcode.com/microsoft-net/post-and-wcf-rest-service/)

Comment: No it's not compulsory. Actually you can find more information about this paramater here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @FloChanz Yes,still not getting the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Decorate your service class with follwing attribute

   ```
   [ServiceContract]
   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
   public class Service1
   ```
2. Web.config should look like this

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <configuration>
         <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
         </system.web>
         <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
               <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            </modules>
         </system.webServer>
         <system.serviceModel>
           <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
             <standardEndpoints>
               <webHttpEndpoint>
                 <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
               </webHttpEndpoint>
             </standardEndpoints>
         </system.serviceModel>
       </configuration>
   ```
3. Your Global.asax should look like this.

   ```
   public class Global : HttpApplication
   {
       void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         RegisterRoutes();
       }

       private void RegisterRoutes()
       {
       // Edit the base address of Service1 by replacing the "Service1" string below
           RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service1", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: please tell me which assembly should be add in service class. because I am getting error in AspNetCompatibilityRequirements  in this line

Comment: Global.asax                                                         1.Create an empty new project. 
2.Go to that folder and copy the Global.asax file. 
3.Go to your project and in solution explorer paste it on root.
4.Open Global.asax file and change namespace match to your namespace.
5.In solution explorer right click on Global.asax and pick View Markup and change inherits match to your namespace.                 
AspNetCompatibilityRequirements :                                   1.Assembly:System.ServiceModel                                     2. Namespace:System.ServiceModel.Activation