# WCF Service cannot return JSON of List of objects

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have an object defined as below.  From my WCF Service I can return a List with no problems, but when I try to return as Json, it returns zero bytes.  No error.

I have about 80 other methods in this project with no problems, but this one will simply not convert.   I could change Serializer to NewtonSoft but this is nearing the end of this project. I've never seen this issue before.

My objectX is as below, is there something I've missed?

```
public class objectX
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LinkedId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateProcessed { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProcessedBy { get; set; }
        public int BranchId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ModifiedBy { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is the contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    UriTemplate = "objectX/Read/{clientId}/{branchId}/{statuses}/{dateTime}",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<objectX> objectXRead(string clientId, string branchId, string statuses, string dateTime);
```

Comment: Is the `List<objectX>` empty?

Comment: @DerekW currently it contains 7 objectX, yet nothing is returned at all, and viewing in Fiddler shows zero bytes.  That is by adding a watch I can see that it is populated, but when the WCF returns the collection... well, it doesn't.

Comment: Show the WCF contract you are using....

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, I added the OperationContract

Comment: did you try decorating the class and its properties with the correct contract attributes? i.e DataContract etc... )

Comment: @Ahmedilyas i think i've found the issue, i'll explain below.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing wrong with Serializer, I have Web API project and I have used your object here is my method in controller

```
public List<objectX> GetObjectX()
    {
        return new List<objectX>() { new objectX() { CompanyName = "c1", BranchName = "b1" },
        new objectX() { CompanyName = "c2", BranchName = "b2" }};
    }

public class objectX
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LinkedId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateProcessed { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProcessedBy { get; set; }
        public int BranchId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

I am getting below result.

[{"CompanyName":"c1","Username":null,"BranchName":"b1","Amount":null,"Id":0,"ClientId":0,"UserId":0,"TypeId":0,"Credits":0,"InvoiceDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Notes":null,"LinkedId":null,"Status":null,"DateProcessed":null,"ProcessedBy":null,"BranchId":0,"CreatedOn":null,"CreatedBy":null,"ModifiedOn":null,"ModifiedBy":null},{"CompanyName":"c2","Username":null,"BranchName":"b2","Amount":null,"Id":0,"ClientId":0,"UserId":0,"TypeId":0,"Credits":0,"InvoiceDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Notes":null,"LinkedId":null,"Status":null,"DateProcessed":null,"ProcessedBy":null,"BranchId":0,"CreatedOn":null,"CreatedBy":null,"ModifiedOn":null,"ModifiedBy":null}]

Please check your configuration if it has some restrictions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

take a look here:

[How do I return clean JSON from a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service)

I believe you are not telling WCF how to return the data via the attributes on the contract. you don't tell us what the WCF Contract looks like.

Comment: Could be.  Though to date there are a total of 432 contracts in the services I've set-up (it's a large project) and this is the first time I've came across this error.  Too much wood to see the trees?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what was causing the issue, though it does not make sense to me.  The data that populates the object comes from an azure db (sql server).  Within a proc there, the InvoiceDate was set to the min date in error (it was incorrectly being saved from a null value and cast to 01/01/1001 00:00).  Albeit still a true datetime, and it being stored in the object in memory as a true datetime, only when it was sent to the db as real date, was I able to return the object in JSON.

I see not reason why this should be the case.  The data is returned from the proc as 01/01/01 00:00, a true datetime value, hence I would expect c# to treat it as such.  Even when doing a test check to see if the date returned from the proc was <= DateTime.Min (c#), and setting it to DateTime.Min (again) in code, it would also work.  But the straightforward 'cast' from the db value of 01/01/01 00:00 to datetime would not work.

More confusing is that it returned in tests, in XML, with no issues.

Thanks to @Mitesh for prompting me to set up a simple test that led to this 'discovery'.