# Want to return JSON format from my existing WCF application which is SOAP based

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, design-patterns

Would like to create one wrapper for WCF application which will return JSON. Can you please suggest, how will I proceed to create wrapper for WCF application, where this wrapper will return JSON.

Do not want to change my existing application as my web application is already consuming this. I would like to consume this service for mobile application.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service?rq=1) and its answers

Answer (score 0):

This should tell you all you need to know: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-sec