# Displaying JSON Data In <Select> Using AngularJS (Error)

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am having an issue with displaying JSON data that I am getting passed to display in a html  control.

I have set-up module which all looks correct and fine:

```
//Define an angular module for our app
var AngularJSTest = angular.module('AngularJSTest', ['ui.router']);

//Define Routing for the application
AngularJSTest.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.
        state('home', {
            name: 'home',
            templateUrl: 'AngularJSTestPage.html',
            controller: 'AngularJSTestPageCtrl'
        })
}]);
```

Then in my controller I am getting my JSON data and storing in `testAccounts`:

```
AngularJSTest.controller("AngularJSTestPageCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:53215/IBookService.svc/GetBooksList').success(function (data) {

        $scope.testAccounts = data;
        $scope.selectedTestAccount = $scope.testAccounts[0];

    });
}]);
```

I have tested that my results are coming back as I wrote:

```
Console.log($scope.testAccounts);
```

This returned all my JSON which looks like the following:

```
[{"BookName":"test1","ID":1},{"BookName":"test2","ID":2},{"BookName":"test","ID":3}]
```

Finally, in my html I am using 'ng-options' and selecting all the 'BookName' from my JSON data:

```
<body ng-app="AngularJSTest">
<div ng-controller="AngularJSTestPageCtrl">
    <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="selectedTestAccount" data-ng-options="item.BookName for item in testAccounts">
        <option label="-- ANY --"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Error**

The error happens when I load up my project the  control shows a list of  84 labels which say 'undefined'.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

**EDIT**

Here is what the URL returns:

[JSON Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXBPJ.png)

**EDIT 2**

I am getting my data from WCF Service like below, is this incorrect?

```
    public List<DC_BOOK> Books()
    {

        List<DC_BOOK> listBook = new List<DC_BOOK>();

        DC_BOOK books = new DC_BOOK();
        books.ID = 1;
        books.BookName = "test1";
        listBook.Add(books);

        DC_BOOK books1 = new DC_BOOK();
        books1.ID = 2;
        books1.BookName = "test2";
        listBook.Add(books1);

        DC_BOOK books2 = new DC_BOOK();
        books2.ID = 3;
        books2.BookName = "test";
        listBook.Add(books2);

        return listBook;


    }

    public string GetBooksList()
    {
        using (SampleDbEntities entities = new SampleDbEntities())
        {
            // Serialize the results as JSON
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(Books().GetType());
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, Books());

            // Return the results serialized as JSON
            string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            return json;
            //return entities.Books.ToList();

        }



    }
```

Comment: There must be something else wrong as this works fine http://jsfiddle.net/wb58yd6r/

Comment: @Ben Clarke try to double check data returned from `http://localhost:53215/IBookService.svc/GetBooksList` your code looks OK.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker What else could be wrong, I will attached an image of the JSON returned from the URL

Comment: @drax I have added an image to the question to what the URL returns.

Comment: Does the service set correct content types? Since to me it looks like your data is just pure string, not json. Here is fiddle with repro: http://jsfiddle.net/wb58yd6r/1/

Comment: And if that is the case you can fix it on service side or just call `JSON.parse` on data, before you assign it to `$scope.testAccounts`

Comment: @drax I have pasted my WCF service in the EDIT. I think you might be right about the string ... If so, how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, the returned string is exactly 84 characters long and you are getting 84 undefined errors.  It seems that your `svc` isn't returning proper JSON headers and hence the returned JSON string is being treated as an array of 84 elements.
Try this:

```
AngularJSTest.controller("AngularJSTestPageCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:53215/IBookService.svc/GetBooksList').success(function (data) {

        $scope.testAccounts = JSON.parse(data);
        $scope.selectedTestAccount = $scope.testAccounts[0];

    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this worked. Does this mean i have to fix my svc?

Comment: You just need to configure your svc to return correct JSON instead of a string. I'm not familiar with svc but perhaps this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service

Answer (score -1):

So after building out this example I didn't have an issue with box not loading the data correctly. 
the only thing that i changed was the way the variable on the scope was being assigned

```
$scope.testAccounts = data;
$scope.selectedTestAccount = data[0];
```

[Here is my plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/adrs3fiBbZkSMpl6GdNM?p=preview)

Comment: So, is your issue solved or is there still a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it maybe beause im using a WCF service to call the JSON?