# Return different Object (List or error class) from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I am trying to build a WCF service which has a single method `getPersonList` which returns list of person like this

```
[
  {"personId":121, "personName":"John Smith"},
  {"personId":953, "personName":"Maggie Johnson"}
]
```

If there is some error, I want to return an error response like this from the same method.

```
{"errorCode":4002,"errorMessage":"invalid request token"}
```

Now I have my Service Contract as below:

```
    [ServiceContract()]
    public interface IPersonContract
    {
        [OperationContract()]
        Object GetPersonList(int requestParam);
    }
```

and my sample `GetPersonList` method

```
Object GetPersonList(int requestParam)
{
  if (requestParam == 1)
  {
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
    error.ErrorCode = 4002;
    error.ErrorMessage = "invalid request token";

    return error;
  }else
  {
    List<Person> returnList = new List<Person>();
    // add Person to returnList
    return returnList;
  }

}
```

Person Class

```
[DataContract()]
public class Person
{

    [DataMember(Name = "personName")]
    String PersonName{   get;   set;  }

    [DataMember(Name = "personId")]
    String PersonID {   get;   set;  }

}
```

Error Class

```
[DataContract()]
public class ErrorResponse
{

    [DataMember(Name = "errorCode")]
    int ErrorCode{   get;   set;  }

    [DataMember(Name = "errorMessage")]
    String ErrorMessage{   get;   set;  }

}
```

I looked up `KnownTypes` for DataContract classes but how do I apply that on `Object`.

If I add fields from `ErrorReponse` and add `List<Person>` in a single class and return that object, I get a response like this in success case which is not what I want.

```
{
"Person":[{"personId":121, "personName":"John Smith"},
      {"personId":953, "personName":"Maggie Johnson"}]
}
```

Comment: check this link , yuo missed the [WebMethod...] decoration i think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just serialize into JSON the response and make the client determine (after de-serializing) whether an error occurred?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath - this is just a simple example of a complex scenario. there may be multiple error conditions. so we would need different structure for positive and negative cases

Comment: @KarouiHaythem - thanks, I forgot to add that in this example

Comment: Simply leverage the mechanisms WCF already offers: use FaultContracts and throw a FaultException. Search for "wcf fault handling" to find plenty of information.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Great, thanks. that helped a lot. I was able to use my error class with `FaultException<>` without changing the Contract return type to Object

Comment: Nice, happy to be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your service contract definition like -

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "/get/{id}")]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(RootObject1))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(RootObject2))]
    object GetOrder(string id);
```

service implementation -

```
    public object GetOrder(string id)
    {
        if (id.Length == 1)
        {
            return new RootObject1 { errorCode = 4002, errorMessage = "invalid request token" };
        }
        return new RootObject2 { personId = 121, personName = "John Smith" };
    }
```

[image]

[image]

---

### **Updated on 12/27/2016 for List type**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetOrdersJSON?ClientID={ClientID}&SenderEmail={SenderEmail}&VersionNumber={VersionNumber}")]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<MyCustomErrorDetail>))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<ShipToDetails>))]
    object GetOrdersJSON(int ClientID, string SenderEmail, string VersionNumber);


[DataContract]
public class MyCustomErrorDetail
{
    public MyCustomErrorDetail(string errorInfo, string errorDetails)
    {
        ErrorInfo = errorInfo;
        ErrorDetails = errorDetails;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorInfo { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorDetails { get; private set; }
}
```

Return the below object from GetOrdersJSON when there are no records or when any other error occurs depending on your need!

```
                MyCustomErrorDetail myCustomErrorObject = new MyCustomErrorDetail("There are no records available", string.Format("There are no records available for user {0}", fstr_UserName));
                List<MyCustomErrorDetail> myCustomErrorList = new List<MyCustomErrorDetail>();
                myCustomErrorList.Add(myCustomErrorObject);
                return myCustomErrorList;
```

Comment: thanks, didn't knew about about `ServiceKnownType`. will definately have a look

Answer (score 0):

In mine I just returned a standard HTTPResponseException like this:

```
    public clsUserInfo Get(String id, String pwd)
    {
        clsResultsObj<clsUserInfo> retVal = new clsResultsObj<clsUserInfo>();

        retVal = bizClass.GetUserByIDAndPWD(id, pwd);

        if (retVal.IsSuccessful & retVal.Payload != null)
        {
            return retVal.Payload;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

    }
```

But you can take it a step further with something like this for your own custom error messages:

```
{ 
    throw new WebFaultException<string>(string.Format(“There is no user with the userName ‘{0}’.”, userName), HttpStatusCode.NotFound); 
}
```